# presentViewController shows not all elements on presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift2, viewcontroller, xcode-storyboard, presentviewcontroller

I encountered a problem while trying to present a new view controller within a storyboard using following code:

```
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIdentifier")
    self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The view controller does appear, but shows for some reason only two buttons, no other elements.

What have I tried so far:

- Loading the view controller as initial view controller to see if the
  problem remains.
  *No, all elements are at the right position.*
- Switching animated from true to false. *Problem still remains*
- Printing the hidden attribute as well as x and y positions. *Hidden
  is false, and the positions are what they are supposed to be*
- Cleaning and rebuilding the project, since this seems to fix 99% of
  all strange bugs based on my experience. *Sadly this helped not this
  time*
- Setting hidden first on true, then on false. *Resetting the attribute
  does not help.*
- Using `CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())` . *Does not help
  either.*

I have a simple drawing of what my view looks like attached.
[image: view controller]

As stated, the view controller is shown perfectly fine when I load it as initial view controller, but only the buttons are shown when using the code above.
ViewDidAppear is called as well.

I am using Xcode Version 7.2.1

EDIT:
As requested by comment, this is my code for the view controller to be presented:

```
import UIKit

class myViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }


}
```

Edit:
I found a solution to this problem:
By creating the transition within the following block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

});
```

It appears that my problem was, that the lines that trigger said transition weren't executed on the UI thread. I still have no idea why this lead to the behaviour explained above, but at least there is a solution.

Comment: Click and select each UI Controls in Storyboard ViewController file. 
Go to Editor->Arrange->Send to Front. Try doing this.

Comment: can you show the code in the viewController being presented?

Comment: @Ted I edited the question to show the code, but as you can see it is nothing impressive. I just turned off the landscape mode so far.

Comment: @Vignesh This made no difference.

Comment: @Nerethar did you add any constraints? if you did, set constraints to all UI controls. and try running

Comment: @Vignesh Yes, I did set them up manually and they work just fine when I start the view controller without this code.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience problems like this can be down to your auto layout constraints being messed up or not quite as you need them (although the fact that it presents correctly when it is the default might suggest I am not headed down the right path).

Are there any warnings in the storyboard editor that suggest the constraints are not correct? I would also suggesting using the view debugging feature to help troubleshoot. Click on the circled icon when your app is running to show your view hierarchy and then try to find the views you think should be there. It also allows you to look at constraints, so that might help with point 1 above as well.

[image]

Comment: I set the constrains myself manually, and they work fine. I could see it while loading the view as initial view. I also get no warnings or errors regarding constrains. Using the debugging with this icon I see my view controller without the labels (but I can see where they are placed and I see the text in the window to the right). The image views are shown correctly in debug.

Comment: OK...when, i.e. in which function, are you calling the methods to present the VC in question?